# How to save string containing single quotes to Oracle DB in c#

Tags: c#, html

**Hi.. I have to insert the below string into Oracle DB:**

```
    String StrDiv = "<div STYLE=" + "'"+"font-family: " + lblPreviewPane.Font.Name + "; font-size: " + lblPreviewPane.Font.Size + "; color: " + ColorPicker1.Color + ""+"'" + ">" + lblPreviewPane.Text + "</div>";
```

**I get the following in StrDiv:**

```
    "<div STYLE='font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 8pt; color: #CC33CC'>TEXTSAMPLE</div>"
```

But the problem is, when i insert the string into DB,an error is thrown:
**ORA-00917: missing comma**

This is because of the single quotes in the STYLE attribute in .

Kindly guide me with a solution for mentioned issue.

Comment: Hmmm.... escape the quotes so that Oracle accepts them as literal characters? In C#: *Use parameterized queries*.

Comment: What code are you using to insert this value in to your database? I'm guessing you're concatenating a SQL statement, and need to escape the quotes.

Comment: Please, do not concatenate strings into SQL statements. Use parametrized statements.

Answer (score 3):

You can use SQLCommand and SQLCommand.Parameters pass the StrDiv as Parameter and it should be fine

small example:

```
using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES (@StrDiv)")) {

    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StrDiv", StrDiv);
    //...

    myConnection.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `"''"` to escape the `"'"` while inserting the data in db

```
String StrDiv = "<div STYLE=" + "''"+"font-family: " + lblPreviewPane.Font.Name + "; font-size: " + lblPreviewPane.Font.Size + "; color: " + ColorPicker1.Color + ""+"''" + ">" + lblPreviewPane.Text + "</div>";


"<div STYLE=''font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 8pt; color: #CC33CC''>TEXTSAMPLE</div>"
```

Comment: Hi.. I used "''" to escape the "'"...This really worked...Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your single quotes with twice single quote men's single quote two times. use **Replace("'","''")** for replacing single quote with twin single quote.

Comment: Please provide more clarity of what you are trying to achieve. Also specify the technology you are using.